# Unable to send and receive message in smack

Tags: android, smack

I am able to establish connection with openfire ,But i am unable to send or receive messages.The below is the code of chat

```
 bt_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                abc = et_message.getText().toString();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), abc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               ChatPojo cpojo = new ChatPojo(abc,true);
                chatList.add(cpojo);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                int position = chatList.size();
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
                et_message.setText("");

    Chat chat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).createChat(connection.getUser(), new ChatMessageListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message.getBody(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    Message message = new Message("admin2", Message.Type.chat);
                    message.setFrom("admin");
                    message.setBody(abc);
                    try {
                        chat.sendMessage(message);
                    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: how you checked that your connection is established?

Comment: @RahulKhurana.... If i open my application in the admin console it is showing as online,if i close the application it is showing as offilne